# Two same variables with different values in If and else statement

Tags: javascript

Should I just change **payback** and **payback** to **payback1** and **payback2** ? Or is there better way to do it?

```
function play() {
    var bet = document.getElementById("bet").value;
    var pips = Math.round((Math.random()*5)+1);

    if(pips == 1|| pips == 3 || pips == 5){
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "No pay";
    }
    else if(pips == 2|| pips == 4) {
      var payback = 1.25*bet;
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You'll receive: "+payback;

    }
    else {
      var payback = 1.50*bet;
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You'll receive: "+payback;
    }
}
```

***Line 15: 'payback' is already defined.***

I seriously tried coming up with a sensible title...

Comment: what do you do with `payback`?

Comment: It was a typo. I replaced bet with payback.

Comment: All variables created using `var` will be hoisted to the closest function definition. This means that your `payback` function is only defined once but set in two locations. As long as the value of `payback` is ok to be changed, you can stick with using the single variable. It would be better to declare it at the top of the function though.

Comment: Yes! Now I have my answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JaakkoUusitalo if you have solved your problem, feel free to accept one of the answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare it at the beginning and then modify it on your if/else:

```
function play() {
var bet = document.getElementById("bet").value;
var pips = Math.round((Math.random()*5)+1);
var payback;

if(pips == 1|| pips == 3 || pips == 5){
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "No pay";
}
else if(pips == 2|| pips == 4) {
  payback = 1.25*bet;
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You'll receive: "+bet;

}
else {
  payback = 1.50*bet;
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You'll receive: "+bet;
}
```

}

Comment: @JaakkoUusitalo and just in case I would use var bet = Number(document.getElementById("bet").value);

Answer (score 1):

Beside the declaration problem, is it adorable to get a not normalised distribution for your bet program? Your `1` and `6` does not have the same chance like the other numbers. The chance is only 1/2 of the rest.

Please see distribution in your case and some more better distributed values.

```js
var i, count = {}, v;
for (i = 0; i < 12000; i++) {   
    v = Math.round((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    count[v] = (count[v] || 0) + 1;
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(count, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
count = {};
for (i = 0; i < 12000; i++) {   
    v = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    count[v] = (count[v] || 0) + 1;
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(count, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it inline and skip the variable declaration:

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You'll receive: "+(1.25*bet);
```

Comment: Of course. It seems that there are multiple ways to do it! Thank you!